# What's the best way to deploy a reactnative app?

Tags: node.js, react-native, docker, kubernetes, expo

I created a react native application with expo. and I use nodejs for backend.
my application is ready and works well locally. now i would like to deploy it and i would like to know what are the good methods to deploy it should i use docker kubernetes etc... if or what platforms would you recommend me.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the stackoverflow community!

For frontend I would suggest deploying it to the google play on android, or app store on ios. But you would need to pay a fee of $99 per year to deploy apps to the apple app store.

If you would like to deploy to other platforms, try to deploy to the official stores, because official stores have more traffic and can be trusted by more people. Thus getting more customers or users to your app.

For backend I would use heroku to deploy my backend code, I have many projects on heroku and it works fine, also it has a free plan for hosting your app. But it's not just flowers and roses, heroku is quite hard to deal with and their service is not the best in my experiences. If you are looking for a enterprice way, I suggest google cloud or firebase, It may cost some money however the performance, the service and user interface is way better than heroku.

More information about heroku: `https://heroku.com/`

More information about google cloud: `https://cloud.google.com`

More information about firebase: `https://firebase.google.com/`

More information about how to deploy: `https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/app-stores/`

More information about Apple app store: `https://developer.apple.com/programs/`

More information about google play store: `https://play.google.com/console/about/guides/releasewithconfidence/`

Tutorials that may be useful:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IPr7oOugTs`

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D3X6Xl5c_Y`

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWK7kesoCQY`

Hope this helps!

NOTE: I'm not sponsored by ANY of the companies above, and I'm just a regular human being on the internet.